# Inform7: How can I create a random chance event in a specific circumstance in inform7?

Tags: random, inform7

I would like to make a functionality in my Inform7 game:

When the player decides to go through the crosswalk by going north, in the first time the narrator will indicate to the player that there is a chance that the player will die, and if the player types going north again, then the event will happen and in a randome chance of 1 in 2 succeeds, the player will be able to go to the Garden.
Like this:

```
        Instead of going north in the road for the second time when a random chance of 1 in 2 succeeds:
        say "Yay! You made it!";
        now the player is in the Garden.

        otherwise:
        say "The car crashed you instantly - without any hope, you lost your whole strength in your body…";
        end the game in death.
```

Yes, this code does not work.. could anyone help me figure out how to make this work?

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with this code:

1. Inform doesn't allow a `when` clause after `for the second time`. (You *can* write it the other way around, as in "when a random chance of 1 in 2 succeeds for the second time", but that means something different: it would trigger the rule the second time the random chance succeeded, that is, the second time the player survived crossing the road.)
2. `otherwise` has to be part of an `if` statement; it can't be used with a `when` clause.

To fix the code, you can just move the "random chance" condition into an `if` statement, then change the punctuation so both alternatives are part of the same rule:

```
[I added these lines to make a complete example...]
Road is a room.

Garden is a room, north of Road.

Instead of going north in the road for the first time:
    say "The road looks dangerous. You hesitate a moment, unsure if you really want to take the risk."

[And here's the fixed rule:]
Instead of going north in the road for the second time:
    if a random chance of 1 in 2 succeeds:
        say "Yay! You made it!";
        now the player is in the Garden;
    otherwise:
        say "The car crashed you instantly - without any hope, you lost your whole strength in your body…";
        end the game in death.
```